# Laravel cookie storage gets exceeded after every few visits

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies

I have got a bit of a problem with laravel's `remember me` functionality.
Normally, laravel adds a **session cookie**, an **xsrf token** and **a 3rd cookie with a random hash** value. (Pic below)

[image]

When I follow the normal login-do stuff-logout-repeat procedure, everything works fine. ***No extra cookies are added.***

If I login, close the browser and then visit the site again, there's another cookie that gets added. This one looks like the 3rd cookie. On repeating this particular flow, I see there's a major cookie bloat. I'm not even sure all of those gets used. (Pic below)

[image]

When I check `remember me` while logging in, another **remember_me** token gets added. When I close the browser window and visit the site again, I'm logged in automatically. Similar to above scenario, when I repeat this procedure a few times, more and more cookies get added. (Pic below)

[image]

Eventually, I get an error saying

```
Bad request Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.

Cookie
```

The site doesn't even open after that, unless I manually clear out the cookies.

My question is how can I delete the older cookies when I go through the above scenarios? Is there any way Laravel takes care of this that I possibly be missing? Is there any way to delete the older cookie when a new one is getting generated on every visit?

The only question that comes closest to mine is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466388/laravel-authlogout-not-removing-remember-me-cookie), but the answer didn't work for me.

I'm using Laravel's `AuthController` and my `session.php` looks like so:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => 120,

    'expire_on_close' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => 'zpz_session',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => false,

];
```

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: @Bogdan I'm using 5.2

Comment: Are you using Varnish, nginx or some other caching proxy?

Comment: @Bogdan Nope. This is on a vagrant box. Default apache, no varnish, not using memcached/redis yet.

I am using another plugin called `laravelcollective/html`. Not sure if that would cause this.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 4):

Had same problem and finally realized that I have misconfigured .env in these lines:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.mydomain.sk
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=mydomain.sk
```

should be:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.mydomain.sk
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=.mydomain.sk
```

These comments were helpful: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/31442

Comment: Thanks @Peter, this solution works. I added value like .mydomain.com

Answer (score 1):

Cookie Header has a limit of 4096 bytes (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52492934/49114) and you get this error because encrypted cookies are very large, and every created cookie will add more and more bytes to cookie header.

Possible solutions:

1. Store large data on database instead cookies and use cookies only for references.
2. Disable cookie encryption with `'encrypt' => false,` and avoid to store sensible information into cookies.
3. Disable laravel encrypt cookies and add your own encryption to cookies content.